# Windows - Ansible will not create following directory 'C:\Program Files\myDir'

Tags: windows, ansible

Trying to use Ansible on my Windows instances, but I'm not getting a desired result.
The path `C:\Program Files\myDir` will not be created as Ansible will default to `C:\Windows\Program Files` which is not the same path and at the same time ignoring my `myDir`.

Code:

```
- name: Create directory
  ansible.windows.win_file:
    path: C:\Program Files\myDir
    state: directory
```

[Windows Path Formatting Styles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_usage.html#path-formatting-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

works for me

```yaml
- name: Create directory
  ansible.windows.win_file:
    path: "C:\\Program Files\\myDir"
    state: directory
```